# CORS error but only from AJAX and not from HTML form

Tags: cors

I study web attacks. I find that it is possible to submit a form with HTML from another origin into the victim server. But if I use AJAX then I get a CORS error. Is this the expected behavior? If yes, why? The victim has not set any "Allow-Origin" header at all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is the expected behavior.

Before CORS it was already possible to make cross-origin requests using HTML forms, cross-origin inclusion of images ... . But it was not possible to do cross-origin XHR (Ajax) and thus workarounds were done by developers using the allowed methods.

CORS changed this by loosening the original restrictions and allowing cross-origin XHR in some cases. "Simple" XHR are allowed without asking the server first because the same requests could have been done before with HTML forms etc. All other XHR need a pre-flight request first which checks if the server is accepting the HTTP request.

Comment: Excellent point!  I fully retract my comment (not that I disagreed with your answer anyway).

Comment: I would add that the CORS restrictions restricts reading the response, but the request can be made. So, I’m terms of functionality it’s the same like a form submit. CSRF implementations would address both situations.

Comment: @IonicăBizău: For all but simple requests CORS restricts sending the request in the first place because first a pre-flight request will be done to check if the server allows the sending of the real request. The main points of CORS are to be able to send non-simple requests and also to be able to read the response from cross-origin XHR. Reading the response not only involves sending the request since without explicit CORS policy the request can be send but the result not read.